# condition of $k$ for every continuous function $f$ to have $x$ satisfying $f (x + k) = f (x)$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $A=\{k\mid 0<k<1, \text{ for every continuous function }\,f:[0,1] \to \Bbb R\, \text{ satisfying }\,f(0)=f(1)=0,\,\text{ there  exists } \, x \,\text{ such  that }\,f(x+k)=f(x)\}$.

What is A? I  already know if $\:0.5<k<1$, let $f(x)=\sin(2\pi x)$, then there is no $x$ such that $f(x+k)=f(x)$. So, $k \notin A$ and if $k=\frac{1}{m+1}$ with $m$ a natural number, $k \in A$. 
How to I determine A?

Comment: $A$ is literally there... maybe you used the wrong notation because, in this case, $A = (0,1)$

Comment: Universal Chord Theorem would be applicable here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $k\in(0,1)\backslash\{\frac{1}{n}\ |\ n\in\mathbb{N}^*\}$; we are going to construct a continuous function $f_k:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f_k(0)=f_k(1)=0$ but $f_k(x)\neq f_k(x+k)$ for all $x$. For this pick any $k$-periodic, continuous function $p_k:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $p_k(0)=0$ and $p_k(1)\neq 0$ (which is possible as $1$ isn't an integer multiple of $k$); for example $p_k(x)=|\sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{k}\right)|$. Then define $f_k:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ by
$$
f_k(x):= p_k(x)-p_k(1)x.
$$
Then $f_k$ is continuous and $f_k(0)=f_k(1)=0$, but for $x\in[0,1-k]$ we have
$$
f_k(x+k)=p_k(x+k)-p_k(1)(x+k)=p_k(x)-p_k(1)x-p_k(1)k\neq p_k(x)-p_k(1)x=f_k(x)
$$
as $p_k(1)k\neq 0$. Thus $A=\{\frac{1}{n}\ |\ n\in\mathbb{N}^*\}$.